# Why does Slick generate a subquery when take() method is called

Tags: sql, scala, slick

I use [Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/) 1.0.0-RC1. I have this definition for table object:

```
object ProductTable extends Table[(Int, String, String, String, Double, java.sql.Date, Int, Option[Int], Int, Boolean)]("products") {
  def id = column[Int]("productId", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def title = column[String]("title")
  def description = column[String]("description")
  def shortDescription = column[String]("shortDescription")
  def price = column[Double]("price")
  def addedDate = column[java.sql.Date]("addedDate")
  def brandId = column[Int]("brandId")
  def defaultImageId = column[Option[Int]]("defaultImageId")
  def visitCounter = column[Int]("visitCounter")
  def archived = column[Boolean]("archived")
  def * = id ~ title ~ description ~ shortDescription ~ price ~ addedDate ~ brandId ~ defaultImageId ~ visitCounter ~ archived
}
```

I need a simple query which selects 8 rows from database:

```
ProductTable.filter(_.title === "something")
  .sortBy(_.visitCounter)
  .map(_.title)
  .take(8)
  .selectStatement
```

And the output is:

```
select x2.x3 from 
   (select x4.`title` as x3 from `products` x4 
     where x4.`title` = 'something' 
     order by x4.`visitCounter` limit 8) x2
```

If I get rid of `take()` method:

```
ProductTable.filter(_.title === "something")
 .sortBy(_.visitCounter)
 .map(_.title)
 .selectStatement
```

then the output is:

```
select x2.`title` from `products` x2 
where x2.`title` = 'something' 
order by x2.`visitCounter`
```

So my question is: Why does Slick generate a subquery when its query object is constructed with `take()` method?

P.S. If it can be related, I use MySql driver with all of these

Comment: flip around map and take

Comment: Have you tried? It makes no change in output SQL

Comment: post to Slick user group, Zeiger will know better than anyone why a sub select is being generated....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a short answer and a long one. The short one is: The subquery is there because so far nobody bothered to remove it.

The longer answer is related to that fact that swapping "map" and "take" does not make any difference, which is due to the compilation of queries being all but simple and straight-forward.

Relatively early in the query compiler there's a "forceOuterBinds" phase which introduces (potentially) lots of extra Bind (a.k.a. flatMap) operations that are semantically equivalent and redundant. The idea is to take some *x* which has a collection type and turn it into *Bind(s, x, Pure(s))* where *s* is a fresh Symbol. If *x* is already of the shape *Pure(y)*, we turn it into *Bind(s, Pure(ProductNode()), Pure(y))* instead. In Scala code, think of this as turning an *x: List[T]* into *x.flatMap(s => List(s))* or a *List(y)* into *List(()).flatMap(s => List(y))*. The purpose of this transformation is to make tree rewriting in the later compiler phases easier by giving us a place to modify the projection (which was created as an identity mapping) in all the places where we might want to do that.

Later on, in "convertToComprehensions", all nodes from the monadic form (Bind, Pure, Filter, Take, Drop, etc.) are converted *individually* to Comprehension nodes (representing a SQL *select* statement). The result is still not legal SQL though: SQL comprehensions are not monad comprehensions. They have very limiting scope rules that do not allow a *from* clause to reference a variable introduced by a previous *from* clause (in the same comprehension or an enclosing comprehension).

That's why we need the next phase, "fuseComprehensions", which may look purely like an optimization at first glance but is actually required to generate correct code. This phase tries to fuse the individual comprehensions as much as possible to avoid these illegal references. We've made some progress with what we can fuse but a 100% solution to the scope problem is not in sight (and in fact, I am pretty sure that it is impossible to solve).

To reiterate that, progress in this phase was mostly driven by the need for *correctness*, not just generating nicer code. So could we remove that extra subquery? Yes, certainly, but nobody has implemented it yet.

If you want to try to implement such an optimization, here are some caveats to think about:

- Are you content with removing purely aliasing projections (i.e. a Comprehension where the *select* slot has the form Some(ProductNode(ch)) where each element of ch is a Path)?
- Or maybe you think that *select x+1 from (... limit ...))* should also be fused. What kinds of expressions can you allow? E.g. would a RowNum be OK?
- What kind of shape does the subquery need to have? For example, may it contain *groupBy* or *orderBy* clauses?

(And something for me to think about: How long would it take to implement that optimization compared to explaining why it doesn't yet exist?)

Comment: Is your answer still valid in Slick 3.0 ? Or has something changed which I can't find.