# get 6 random records with slick 3.0 and postgresql

Tags: postgresql, scala, random, slick

I need a little help with writing the correct slick (3.0) syntax for getting 6 random rows from a table.

I would like to convert:

```
select * from [table]
order by random()
limit 6
```

into slick code.

I have found this page http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/sql-to-slick.html#index-11. But being new to scala and slick i can't do it on my own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
val rand = SimpleFunction.nullary[Double]("random")
db.run(Tables.sortBy(x=>rand).take(6).result)
```

This generate next sql:

```
select x2."field1", x2."field2" from 
(select x3."field1" as "field1", x3."field1" as "field2" from "Table" x3 order by random() limit 6) x2
```

And why does slick generate a subquery, you can find here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14483343/3624079